# What is ${\displaystyle \mathbb {R} }^*$? If its the domain, and co-domain is ${\displaystyle \mathbb {R} }$, f(x) = $Q+1 \over Q$. Prove Surjectivity

Tags: functions

I can simplify f(x) to $1\over Q$+1  but I'm lacking in the logic part of proving it.

Comment: Maybe it is $\mathbb R$ minus $\{ 0 \}$...

Comment: What is [Suriectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function)? Maybe we have to start from the def...

Comment: See [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597873/let-f-r-to-r-with-fx-x1-x-explain-whether-it-is-injective)

Comment: If it is R - {0}, then I think it is surjective.. But I still need some help writing the formal proof